# What's the difference between http_file and http_archive Bazel rules?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I've been working with several bazel rules recently, but I would like to know whether `http_file` and `http_archive` can be used interchangeably or if they complement each other as for example `native.local_repository`, `native.new_local_repository`, and `new_local_repository` are complementary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http_archive` expects an archive and extracts it, whereas `http_file` does not perform an "extract" operation. Furthermore, `http_file` creates a file group, and `http_archive` "embeds" an external workspace. That are two completely different things.

Comment: What do you mean by `"embeds" an external workspace`?

Comment: http_file introduces a new external workspace, which targets are accessible via `@my_other_workspace_name//package/sub_package:my_target"

Comment: I got it. That's very clear now in theory and also applied in practice. Thanks!